# Assumption on the bound of variables

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, second-order-logic

To quote from the [book](http://tata.gforge.inria.fr/) in Lemma 3.3.4, we assume that all variables in the formula are bound at most once. Why is this restriction placed? Clearly the language with such a restriction is a subset of the language without the bound. Would it be reasonable to assume that these two languages are equivalent, and if so, how? 
[image]

Comment: "without the bound" ??? I think that "variables in the formula are bound at most once" must mean that each variable occurs at most one in the scope of a quantifier ( it is bound vs it is free).

Comment: I cannot understand the context of the quote, but IMO it means simply that a formula like $\forall x (P(x) \land \exists x Q(x))$ - which is **not** wrong - must be avoided and replaced by $\forall x (P(x) \land \exists y Q(y))$. If so, it is not a limitation at all, because usual Language for FOL has un unlimited supply of variables.

Comment: Compare your expression about "the bound of variables" with the text saying : "all variables are bound at most once in the formula".

Comment: Presumably Proposition 3.3.1 is the statement that they are equivalent (or at least that we can translate the full syntax to the restricted syntax without changing meaning). As to why it is done, it's convenience. If all (bound) variables are bound exactly once, then every occurrence of a variable refers to the same thing. If not, then we'd need to talk about the $x$ bound by this quantifier as opposed to that other one. This is somewhat noisy and awkward especially when you want to formalize it (though, it is straightforward to formalize).